# Can I use water flow meter for measuring flow of glycol accurately. Why yes/no?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, water-pressure

I have water flow meter and I was wandering if i could reuse it in new project for glycol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BUT the meter was designed and calibrated for a density, viscosity and temperature.

So, you will need to re-calibrate it for the fluid you wish.